# Call a Javascript function with PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have a login script that checks whether or not a user has logged in before simply using a value in a mysql database. `1 for previously logged in and 0 for never logged in before.` Right now it re-directs to a different page based on the value.

```
if ($member['prev_log_in'] == 0)
    {
         header("location: ../accountSetUp.php");
    }
    else
    {
         header("location: ../dashboard.php");
    }
```

Rather than re-direct to a different page I would like it to still take the new user to the dashboard, but show a Modal from bootstrap with the new user info.

The regular protocol for loading a modal is by a user clicking a button or link like so: that calls the modal.

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

So, I'm not sure how you could call the modal to load from the php. Even if the modal loaded while still on the login page would be fine. I just want the php script to display the modal if the user has never logged in before. I just don't know how to do it. Any thoughts would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to open the dashboard.php in modal?

Comment: No, I want the modal to show up with information about the new account. Just like a normal modal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($member['prev_log_in'] == 0){
    header("location: ../accountSetUp.php");
}else{
    echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#my-modal').modal(options)
    });</script>";
}
```

and `<div id="my-modal"><iframe src="../dasboard.php"></div>`

EDIT:

If you want to only open automatically the bootstrap modal when user enter to dashboard you can only put these lines in dashboard.php:

```
 <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
             $('#my-modal').modal(options)
 });
 </script>
```

RE-EDIT:

Ok: If it was not logged in before:

PUT These lines in **dashboard.php**

```
if ($member['prev_log_in'] == 0){
    echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#my-modal').modal(options)
    });</script>";
}else{
    echo "You were logged in";
}
```

and `<div id="my-modal"><iframe src="../accountSetUp.php"></div>`

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Just in case this does work. (i'm sure it will) my question was for Never Logged in "0" to have the modal displayed. You have it the other way, Can you just switch that around so I can accept your answer? Just to keep the stack overflow rules satisfied :)

Comment: Ok, would you put the `<div id="my-modal">` within the login script page or on the login page? I tried it with the login script page and it seems to just stop the login script.

Comment: You must put in in dashboard.php, because in this page the modal appears. You must put the PHP lines in dashboard.php because you want to have in the background of modal, the dashboard.php page... @user2371301

Comment: So from Google Chromes Console I receive this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined login-exec.php:1` My script for logging in is in a separate folder. The login process just stops and it displays a blank white page. With this code.

Comment: Have you put these lines in dashboard.php?

Comment: have you loaded bootstrap.js here?

Comment: You're welcome! If you have any other questions, do not hesitate to contact me!

Comment: Well your answer may be the solution. But I guess I have a bigger problem. I added a button to the page to test and it still doesn't load. I'm still getting that jQuery is not defined error on that page as well. I have jquery and the bootstrap.js file linked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32536/discussion-between-user2371301-and-itchristian)